# React Material UI + Router redirect button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, jsx

I am trying to use Material-UI for React but I am not sure about the proper way to redirect to other pages / components.

I have read several sites about the different ways to redirect using `react-router-dom`, but still, I don't get the "final" way.

## `history.push`:

One of the ways that didn't work for me was using `props.history.push('/some-route')`. I get that `history` is undefined. I also tried accesing it through `props.history`:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const Page = props => {
    const { history } = props;

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                onClick={() => history.push('/some-route')}
            >My Button</Button>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

## Redirect Component

Another way that didn't work for me was using the same `react-router-dom` Redirect component. Here I don't get any error, it just does nothing when clicking:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Page = props => {
    const { history } = props;

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                onClick={() => <Redirect to={'/some-route'} />}
            >My Button</Button>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

## Links with styles

I have found the only way that is still working with `react-router-dom` Link Components where I pasted the same generated classes names:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Page = props => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Link
                class="MuiButtonBase-root-124 MuiButton-root-98 MuiButton-contained-109 MuiButton-containedPrimary-110 MuiButton-raised-112 MuiButton-raisedPrimary-113 MuiButton-sizeLarge-122"
                to="/some-route"
            >My Button</Button>
        </Link>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

And the last one that I didn't even try since I guess it's wrong is inserting a Button component inside a Link component (or viceversa).

Which way do you recommend to redirect when clicking a button? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: if your history object is undefined, have you checked why? Does `<Page />` receive it as props?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easier way is to pass the react-router-dom `Link` to the `component` property of the Material UI button:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

    ...

    <Button component={Link} to="/some-route" color="primary">
      MyButton
    </Button>

    // OR

    const MyLink = props => <Link to="/some-route" {...props} />

    <Button component={MyLink} color="primary">
      MyButton
    </Button>
```

Material UI example: https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library

Comment: Documentation about the `component` property: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#component-prop

Answer (score 1):

For those using Fraction's solution but running into error `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`, the solution is to wrap whatever custom element Link is used in in a `BrowserRouter`, e.g.

```
// App.js

...

<BrowserRouter>
   CustomElement
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
//CustomElement.js

...

return (
    <Button component={Link} to="/some-route" color="primary">
      MyButton
    </Button>
)
```